# Debugging Override Fucntions in Visual Stuio does not work

Tags: c#, overriding, visual-studio-debugging, asp.net-core-3.1, nopcommerce

I have a base class with function MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems

```
public partial class OrderProcessingService : IOrderProcessingService
{
    protected virtual void MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems(PlaceOrderContainer details, Order order)
    {
     …
    }
}
```

Then in a plugin I have class which inherits and a function that overrides MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems

```
public partial class CustomOrderProcessingService : OrderProcessingService
{
    protected override void MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems(PlaceOrderContainer details, Order order)
    {
    …
    }
}
```

The classes are registered via `AutoFac`. When debugging the base function `MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems` gets called. The override function `MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems` does not get called.

When it runs in production this code works and the correct function gets called. It is a frustration when you try to debug the code and it does not work in debug?

I logged an issue on [Visual Studio Developer](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Base-class-override-does-not-called-when/1256143) but no response there

Does anyone have an insight into why the debugger does not work correctly?

Comment: My guess this is a bug and something to do with the partial class and the method not getting called in the debug runtime overload resolution process

Comment: Also note, I cant reproduce your results and core 3.1 and latest VS. So your setup is different to my test somehow. Even when i create separate partial classes, and put them all in separate files.

Comment: I think you need to at least get a [mcve]. Because at the moment there are way too degrees of freedom in your question to validate anything

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Here is a test case https://dotnetfiddle.net/srlurM

If you change

public override int MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems()

to

public virtual int MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItems()

then it acknowledges an override is needed

Comment: So in the current code, you would expect 2 to print ?

Comment: Yes - I just edited that fiddle code to call the function directly and it prints 2
The scenario is the base function is in the nopCommerce core which is .netcore3.1 The override function is in is a plugin that is loaded dynamically at runtime. I have the same code in a previous version of nopCommerce running .netcore2.2  and that all works perfectly in the debugger as expected.

Comment: I can get the `print 2` under your code. Did you try to [reset vs settings](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1227) or disable any third party extensions?